Trying to use Node-Red Dashboard 2.0 ui-template with Vue v-date-picker
Using ui-template from Dashboard 2.0 I use the code and node-red flow below to try and get the date selected to be sent in a node-red message, but can not get the debug node to display anything. Have tried many versions of the code and all of the suggestions from copilot and gemini to no avail.  Any input is welcomed.  Component displays and seem to select properly but no message.
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <v-date-picker v-model="selectedDate" @change="sendDate" />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      selectedDate: null,
    };
  },
  methods: {
    sendDate() {
      this.$emit('date_picked', this.selectedDate);
    },
  },
};
</script>

and the node-red flow
[
    {
        "id": "6d40c240f7e12805",
        "type": "ui-template",
        "z": "513b99fa31e5eec8",
        "group": "ec50090ef36dcfd7",
        "page": "",
        "ui": "",
        "name": "Select_Analysis_Date",
        "order": 0,
        "width": 0,
        "height": 0,
        "head": "",
        "format": "<template>\n  <div id=\"app\">\n    <v-date-picker v-model=\"selectedDate\" @change=\"sendDate\" />\n  </div>\n</template>\n\n<script>\nexport default {\n  data() {\n    return {\n      selectedDate: null,\n    };\n  },\n  methods: {\n    sendDate() {\n      this.$emit('date_picked', this.selectedDate);\n    },\n  },\n};\n</script>\n\n",
        "storeOutMessages": true,
        "passthru": true,
        "resendOnRefresh": true,
        "templateScope": "local",
        "className": "",
        "x": 540,
        "y": 680,
        "wires": [
            [
                "4b19ea276f8d9ac6"
            ]
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": "4b19ea276f8d9ac6",
        "type": "debug",
        "z": "513b99fa31e5eec8",
        "name": "debug 53",
        "active": true,
        "tosidebar": true,
        "console": false,
        "tostatus": false,
        "complete": "true",
        "targetType": "full",
        "statusVal": "",
        "statusType": "auto",
        "x": 940,
        "y": 680,
        "wires": []
    },
    {
        "id": "ec50090ef36dcfd7",
        "type": "ui-group",
        "name": "Analysis Parameters",
        "page": "f28a66e1d61b8444",
        "width": "12",
        "height": "1",
        "order": 1,
        "showTitle": true,
        "className": "",
        "visible": "true",
        "disabled": "false"
    },
    {
        "id": "f28a66e1d61b8444",
        "type": "ui-page",
        "name": "Dashboard 2.0 Test Page",
        "ui": "957559fb8731ef90",
        "path": "/pageN",
        "icon": "home",
        "layout": "grid",
        "theme": "206b56fa3aa06394",
        "order": -1,
        "className": "",
        "visible": "true",
        "disabled": "false"
    },
    {
        "id": "957559fb8731ef90",
        "type": "ui-base",
        "name": "My Dashboard",
        "path": "/dashboard",
        "includeClientData": true,
        "acceptsClientConfig": [
            "ui-notification",
            "ui-control"
        ],
        "showPathInSidebar": false,
        "navigationStyle": "default"
    },
    {
        "id": "206b56fa3aa06394",
        "type": "ui-theme",
        "name": "Default Theme",
        "colors": {
            "surface": "#ffffff",
            "primary": "#0094CE",
            "bgPage": "#eeeeee",
            "groupBg": "#ffffff",
            "groupOutline": "#cccccc"
        },
        "sizes": {
            "pagePadding": "12px",
            "groupGap": "12px",
            "groupBorderRadius": "4px",
            "widgetGap": "12px"
        }
    }
]


LLM's are unlikely to be helpful as Dashboard 2.0 is way too new. You will likely do better posing this on the Node-RED discourse forum, but I have forwarded a link to the question to the Dashbord v2.0 dev.

Using the Vue devtools or having some docs might help you more than any kind of LLM indeed.

Thanks for the lead on devtools .... unfortunately "Vue.js is detected on this page.
Devtools inspection is not available because it's in production mode or explicitly disabled by the author." Oh well ...

You can find the docs on sending messages back to Node-RED Editor here: https://dashboard.flowfuse.com/nodes/widgets/ui-template.html#sending-messages-to-node-red - it includes an example of @click and @update:model-value - I think the latter is more likely relevant to you here.
@change should work in theory, but Vuetify, which we use as our component library, is fairly inconsistent in it's implementation, so the @update:model-value is more reliable

All input continues to be welcomed but this works ...any pointers to relevant docs are appreciated...
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <v-date-picker v-model="selectedDate" @click="sendDate" />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      selectedDate: null,
    };
  },
  methods: {
    sendDate() {
      this.send({payload: this.selectedDate})
    },
  },
};
</script>

